# Why does substitution yield a different result to integration? (Kinematics Example)

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, kinematics

**Method 1:**

Let $x=t^2$, find a general solution of $v$ in terms of $x$. (Kinematics, $v=x'(t)$)

$v = 2t$ --> $t = \frac{v}{2}$

so, $x=\frac{v^2}{4}$

**Method 2:**

$a = x''(t) = 2$

$v*\frac{dv}{dx} = 2$

$\frac{dv}{dx} = \frac{2}{v}$

$\frac{dx}{dv} = \frac{v}{2}$

$x = v^2/4 + C$

These differ by a constant, why? Where *exactly* is the error in method 1? I presume that by substituting, you are rejecting additional information. BUT, I don't see *where* the error has been made.

Comment: There is no contradiction between the two methods.  The second method tells you that, for some constant $C$, we have $x = v^2/4+C$.  This is correct.  The value of $C$ is 0, although method 2 doesn't tell you that.  So method 2 is less informative than method 1, but neither method is wrong.  (There is one other weakness of method 2: it involves dividing by $v$, which could be 0.)

Answer (score 2):

The reason you get different answers is because you differentiated each side again. When you differentiate two equations you lose information in general. In this case, you lose information about the constant term.

Both results are the same equation, but in the second case you need to find the value of $C$ that makes the equation true using information you already have. You could, for example, plug in $x=t^2$ and $v=2t$ to solve that $C=0$, but this is basically what you already did in the first problem. This shows that there isn't much worth to solving it in your second method.

Comment: Right. So I was doing a question like this and they used the latter method and assumed an infinite family of solutions. Then they subbed in a made up condition. Is this fallacious?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you mean? Could you elaborate with more specifics.

Comment: they give the initial condition of “v=e^2 when x=6”. I’m not sure if I’m comprehending your answer correctly, but, wouldn’t this be incorrect since it doesn’t end up satisfying C=0?

Comment: @Simplex1 I don't think what they are saying is correct or even makes sense for the reason you included. Unless, there is some mistake in the original problem statement.